# .NET MAUI - Android Development - Cant see browser on emulator - its all black and fuzzy

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, maui

I am starting to develop for mobile devices in .NET MAUI.

**Note:** I am using Visual Studio 2022 to develop although I don't think that could be related.

I have an issue where my **Android emulator** - *Pixel 5 - API 31 (Android 12.0 API 31)* runs everything ok until I need to load the chrome browser on the device.

I have searched around for a solution but as I can't really describe the issue well, I can find a way to fix this.

It is very important as I have just implemented a logon page and obviously, I can't see the browser page to log into my MAUI app.

This is a screen shot of me loading the Google chrome browser on the device:
[image]

Any tips would be great.

thanks
Russ
PS. I just realised I can use, **Firefox** or **Edge** to get around this but it is not the best solution.

Comment: Looks like video memory issues within the emulator, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#accel-graphics . 1) Identify the PC/CPU/GPU/RAM (more for future visitors). 2) Have you tried to recreate the emulator? (i.e. existing emulator image for Chrome is somehow corrupted)

Comment: Tools / Android Device Manager / rt-click that emulator, pick either "Start with Factory Defaults" (resets various system settings; preserves apps and data; cold boots device), or "Factory Reset" (erase/reset everything).

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks for this, will investigate more into the morning. But could you expand on your point number (1). I don’t understand it. Cheers Russ

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks Steve. Will investigate your suggestions in the morning. Cheers Russ

Comment: Asking to documenting your PC and SDK environment. Given its a problem rendering graphics, it could be a problem between the emulator and video driver OR an strange difference with your CPU (AMD vs Intel) OR something with Android SDK version. Just adding info for readers and future visitors. Additionally you may just need to log into Google Play Store on emulator for Chrome app to be updated.